# window.top === window false condition in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, using the

```
window.top === window
```

condition in IE8 always evaluates to false (in other browsers it works fine).
What is the reason for this, and is there any other way for this condition to work cross-browser?

Thanks,

Joel

Comment: ...and definitely not within a frame? :P

Comment: @alex - yup... i am using this code inside a page that is sometimes served inside an iframe. I need to check if it is the top window or an iframe

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a very complicated topic, but the short version is, use `==` when comparing windows, not `===`, because of the "internal" vs. "external" reference aspect of it. You'll find that (for instance) `window === self` is false on some browsers.

Comment: So using "==" for the purpose of checking whether the current window is an iframe or the top window will do the job on all major browsers (window.top == window) ?

Comment: @Joel: Yes, that's my understanding, anyway. (I tripped over this a couple of months back, I'm trying to find the StackOverflow question and answer that I ultimately found that set me straight.)

Comment: J. - Thanks! I will try to look for it myself. For the time being I will update my code to use ==.